# Try-Catch all Exceptions with Zend_Http_Client?

Tags: php, zend-framework, try-catch

I have the following function:

```
public function getClientTable($feedUrl)
{
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client($feedUrl);

    try
    {
        return $client->request()->getBody();
    }
    catch (Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It seems to work great for catching that specific Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception; but what if I want it to catch additional exceptions? Hell, what if I wanted it to catch ALL exceptions... how would I do this?

Also, should I be using "return" or "throw" in the try? Why does it matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple catch statements, eg

```
try { 
    // whatever
} catch (Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception $e) {
    // ah ha
} catch (Zend_Some_other_Exception $e) {
    // ah ha
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // And the final fallback catch that grabs all exceptions
}
```

Comment: Will "Exception" also catch Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception and Zend_Http_Client_Exception?

And should I be using "throw" instead of return?

Comment: The exception will be caught by the first handler that matches it only.

Comment: Rethrow or return depends on how you want the methods calling getClientTable to have to work. Either calls to it catch the exception and handle it as well (ie you rethrow it), or you just return a value that indicates failure and handle that in the caller.

Comment: What I mean is, can I just put catch (Exception), or do I need to do all 3 catches?

Comment: @Jason Axelrod You can. catch (Exception) is the generic version.